# VSCodeでJavaの環境を構築できない

Tags: java, vscode

VSCodeでJavaの環境を構築していたのですが、setting.jsonに
`"java.home":"C:・・・java\openjdk-17.0.2"` と書いても以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
This setting is deprecated, please use 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' instead.
```

初心者なのでいろいろ文章がおかしいかもしれませんがご了承ください。

**環境:**
Windows 10
Java 16.0.2

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

表示されたメッセージを (補足を含めつつ) 翻訳すると以下の様な内容です。

> この設定 (`java.home`) は非推奨です。代わりに `java.jdt.ls.java.home` を使用してください。

お手本にしたページ等では `java.home` を設定している例があるのかもしれませんが、メッセージに出た通り `java.jdt.ls.java.home` に対して PATH を設定してみてください。

もしくは、環境変数 `JDK_HOME` や `JAVA_HOME` が設定されていればそちらも参照するようです。

[Setting the JDK | Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#java-tooling-jdk)

> The path to the Java Development Kit can be specified by the java.jdt.ls.java.home setting in VS Code settings (workspace/user settings). If not specified, it is searched in the following order until a JDK meets current minimum requirement.
>
> - the `JDK_HOME` environment variable
> - the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable
> - on the current system path

Answer (score 0):

`java\openjdk-17.0.2` と記載されているようですが、Windows上ではバックスラッシュを2度重ねる必要があります。

**例:**

```
java\\openjdk-17.0.2
```